# MySQL left join multiple IDs

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I need some help with the following query.
I have the table below and I'm trying to do a JOIN but it's not working as expected:

```
TABLE1
Id1 |  Title
1    |  A
2    |  B
3    |  C

TABLE2
Id2  |  Id1
10   |  1
20   |  1
30   |  1,2
```

So basically the column Id1 on table2 can take more than 1 value.
I have started with the following SQL but it is not working as expected:

```
select t1.id1,count(1) 
from table1 t1 
left join table2 
on t1.id1 = t2.id2 
group by t1.id1 desc;
```

I have also tried to replace t1.id1 = t2.id2 with:
- t1.id1 in t2.id2 
- t1.id1 like concat("%",t2.id2,"%")

but it is still not working as expected.
This query should return all the Ids in table one and should count all the instances of Id1 in table2.

Any thought/suggestion?

Comment: *basically the column Id1 on table2 can take more than 1 value* this is fundamentally flawed

Answer (score 0):

the following SQL is returning the data I needed:

```
select t1.id1,count(t2.id1)
    from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2
    on find_in_set(t1.id1,t2.id1)
    group by t1.id1 desc;
```